# Segfault in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make a very simple program using SFML but i keep getting a segfault.
I'm just trying to make a window for now, it's working when i put everything in the main function but when i try to make a class it keeps segfaulting.

Here is my code:

***main.cpp***

```
int main()
{
    Graphics g(1000, 500, "Window");
    return (0);
}
```

***Graphics.h***

```
class Graphics
{
public:
    Graphics(int width, int height, std::string name);
    ~Graphics();

private:
    sf::RenderWindow _window;
    int _width;
    int _height;
};
```

***Graphics.cpp***

```
Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height, std::string name)
{
//  this->_window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(width, height), name);
    this->_window.setTitle(name);
    this->_window.setSize(sf::Vector2u(width, height));
    this->_width = width;
    this->_height = height;
}

Graphics::~Graphics()
{
}
```

It makes the error at the first line of the constructor:

```
this->_window.setTitle(name);
```

I've also tried to make _window a pointer and to initialize it with a new sf::RenderWindow but it segfaults the same way.

I've used SFML a lot before on Linux and never had this problem. It's my first time using it on Windows.

Comment: Don't post commented out code. Either uncomment it, or remove it.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the 1 line commented code but actually it was here to show what other things i've tried, i thought that maybe it could be useful

Comment: I changed the name to name.c_str() and it works, thanks to the guy who posted the comment and deleted it juste after.

Comment: I highly doubt that really fixed the error.  Unless you know exactly why such a "do-nothing" change to the code fixed the issue, all you did was move the bug to some other part of your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie @elcto Didn't read this note before, but it confirms my suspicion. It does indeed fix the issue, because using `std::string::c_str()` you're passing a raw pointer to the text rather than a complex object. When passing the `std::string`, the version of SFML being used obviously interprets the data wrong, causing the segmentation fault as a result.

Answer (score 1):

sf::Window's default constructor doesn't initializes the window. You need to do it manually with method create(), like:
`this->_window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), name)`
Or, which i better recommend to use, is initialize your window in constructor with member initializer list:

```
Graphics::Graphics(int width, int height, std::string name)
    :    window(sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(width, height), name))
{
...
}
```

Wider explanation on SFML-s docs [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Window.php#a5359122166b4dc492c3d25caf08ccfc4).

Comment: Aaaah, constructors that don't construct. Joy for everyone.

Comment: That still doesn't really explain the segfault, which shouldn't happen, even if the window isn't created yet. This might be a bug or something else.

Comment: I think it's an undefied behavior. There is no actions in Winfows default constructor. Maybe correct answer can be achieved by debugging SFML's sources.

Comment: @GoverNator No need to. If a window isn't created, the internal pointer to the actual implementation isn't set (`m_impl` in the source), causing all member calls to essentially do nothing. As such the segmentation fault has to happen when copying/constructing the parameters passed (a STL string in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be some weird issue outside the code you're showing. Considering it happens when passing a STL object (`std::string`) is there any chance you're somehow mixing different runtime libraries (static vs. shared, debug vs. release)?

Using a `sf::Window` or `sf::RenderWindow` without specifically creating them (either through the constructor with parameters or by calling the `create()` member) doesn't cause a segmentation fault or any other issue. It's supposed to fail silently (by doing nothing).

Here's a short test program:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    std::string test("Hello World!");
    window.setTitle(test);
    return 0;
}
```

When executed, this program will just run for a moment and then end normally (returning `0`) without any errors or anything else. If this still crashes for you, it's most likely your environment.

Since SFML accepts and returns STL objects, it's important that you're using the exact same version inside and outside of SFML (or any other library doing that). So ideally I'd suggest you just compile SFML yourself, which should fix the issue without lots of trial & error.

**Edit:** Since the issue only appears when you're passing a `std::string` and not when passing `char*`, it's indeed the STL class obviously handled by different versions or implementations. Your compiled code passes the object built in some way, but the compiled version of SFML interprets this object in a different way, causing the problem. This will happen with any library. Most just avoid this by simply not allowing you to pass STL (or similar) objects.